# tvOS - Native equivalent for the LoadingTemplate?

Tags: uikit, tvos, tvml

I'm currently developing a native tvOS app (not using TVML), but I would like to use UI elements that are used in TVML (e.g. the LoadingTemplate).
I know that there is a UIActivityView, but that is only the spinner itself.

[image: TVML LoadingTemplate]

Is there a native equivalent for the LoadingTemplate? The UI elements are there, but it would be a pain to exactly rewrite the template with UIKit elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TVML/TVJS provides these pre-defines templates for you, This is one of the benefits of TVML.

UIKit does not. If you want to develop your application natively you will need to re-create the layouts you want using the native elements.

If you just want to use the built in templates and reduce your dev time you may want to consider the TVML option, but this doesnt allow you to easily add more advanced functionality.

See one of my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544607/tvml-vs-custom-app-for-apple-tvos) for a comparison of the two options.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, I know I can do it, it's just hard to get it just the same as the TVML template, if you have any details on the styling, please let me know :)

Comment: it might be worth having a look on github, someone may of already re-created them